# Java ClassNotFoundException predicament

Tags: java, windows, exception, classnotfoundexception, jasperserver

We are getting the following error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.ManagementServiceServiceLocator

We can use the other classes in the JAR (its an import) but this class throws an exception even when another class in the same JAR tries to use it. I have decompiled the JAR to check the class is existent and it is there, so how could I possibly get this error?

Comment: Is the jar on your classpath? (That's rhetorical, it clearly isn't.) Can you show us how you are running the application?

Comment: It's not on the classpath for some reason. Rebuild (reimport) the jar, checking all the build/import paths are correct and should resolve that.

Comment: The JAR is definitely in the classpath as we are calling other methods in it (Which calls a method in a class which is in the same JAR + package and throws the exception).

Comment: The JAR itself might be, but that doesn't necessarily mean every class in that JAR is.

Comment: It does, if a JAR is its contents are too.

Comment: Only in the best case scenario, where everything builds properly. Clearly something's gone wrong with that in your case. Like I suggested, try rebuilding the jar and making sure the paths are what you expect, and that the class is where you expect it to be. Without more information about how you're running the application I can't really be more specific.

Comment: The JAR is a JasperServer API JAR, it is already compiled so the paths and all that are correct (I even decompiled it to check the class was existant).